# How to position a borderless window in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, window, kivy, borderless

I was making an app with Kivy in python, and to make things a tad more stylish, I thought I could remove the border on the window and create by own:

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (900,550)
Window.borderless = True
Config.set('graphics','resizable',0)
```

However the border less window will pop up in the very bottom left corner of my screen. Is there anyway I can position the window so its in the middle of my screen?

If I can't do that, then is there a way to remove the rounded corners on a window?

(I am doing this on a Mac OSX Yosemite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borderless:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics','borderless',1)
Config.set('graphics','resizable',0)
```

*at the top* of your file before anything else. Just the core(Window) will remain.

Position:

```
Config.set('graphics','position','custom')
Config.set('graphics','left',500)
Config.set('graphics','top',10)
```

the same condition applies for all [`Config.set()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html#available-configuration-tokens).

Comment: Hey, exist a mode to move the window without border?