# Why does a borderless Kivy Window shift content down and to the right?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, kivy, sublimetext3

Using Kivy, I want to remove the default border from the App window (removing the close, minimize and maximize buttons). Based on the [Kivy docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html), I want to set the `borderless` value of my `Window` to `True`. However, doing so moves the content of my window down and to the right, exposing the black background color on the top and left sides of the window.

[Screenshot of Window with borderless=False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWRdF.jpg)

[Screenshot of Window with borderless=True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJhkL.jpg)

In the above images, the white within the window is coming from the `Window.clearcolor`, and the black in the `borderless=True` image is what I want to remove, or overlay with the rest of my content.

In the following snippet I have removed all the code that makes up the inner widgets of the kivy App, replacing them with an empty `GridLayout` to show where the content will be.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'My App'
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Window.size = (300, 430)
        Window.borderless = True # This is what is being changed
        return GridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I have read the answers to similar questions regarding [removing the default Kivy window border](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52398496/13650013) and how to [position a borderless Kivy window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544254/how-to-position-a-borderless-window-in-kivy).

Can anyone help diagnose how to shift the contents of my window back to the upper left corner when `borderless` is set to `True`?

Note: This is my first Stackoverflow question, please let me know how to improve it if need be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what the exact issue was, but after troubleshooting several different things within PyCharm (where my original project files were held), on a whim I tried opening the same project with Sublime and the issue is no longer present. When I run the identical code in Sublime, I get the intended result:

[image]

Beautiful! Just how I wanted it. =) I'm sure I somehow goofed up the Kivy settings in Pycharm somehow without realizing it, maybe something with the builder strings? I'm honestly at a loss. But I suppose if by any off chance someone else comes across this, switch up your IDE for a clean slate and give it another go.